# Distributions that are fully specified by second order statistics

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sufficient-statistics

Apart form the Gaussian distribution are there any other distributions that are fully described by second order statistics?

Comment: What constitutes "fully described"? Many families of distributions are parameterized by location and scale parameters which will be directly related to the population mean and variance. Is this sufficient or are you asking about something else?

Comment: I mean, the Gaussian distribution is fully specified by two parameters: mean and variance/covariance... I was wondering whether other distributions are fully specified by these moments... is the 'scale' parameter the same of variance?

Comment: You're repeating what you already said, rather than responding to what I asked. Here's an example -- would you count a continuous [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) on $(a,b)$, which may be rewritten as functions of its mean and standard deviation (specifically t's $U(\mu-\sqrt{3}\sigma,\mu+\sqrt{3}\sigma)$) -- so that given a population mean and standard deviation, I can specify the density and cdf without error -- as being "fully specified" by its moments to second order?

Comment: I'm trying to find out what you're after. If that does count, then a large variety of two-parameter distributions can be similarly reparameterized - the logistic, the gamma, the lognormal. Further, many specific densities can be generalized to location-scale families. But I''m not sure whether that counts as "fully specified" for your purposes.

Comment: Glen_b, yes, I would count that as fully specified by mean and covariance. My original question comes from the fact that when using PCA one might be tempted to think that PCA assumes that the data is Normally distributed just because PCA relies on information contained in the variance of the data. But I guess, since many distributions can be parametrised with mean and covariance then it really does not make sense to think that when using PCA we are implicitly assuming the our data is well represented by a Gaussian distribution. Am I right?

Comment: It would have been better to explain this in your question; firstly, it's now clear you're talking only about multivariate distributions, and secondly PCA involves linear combinations of variables -- that fact is likely to be important in addressing whatever it is you're really trying to ask. Since you already have an answer on this question, it may be best to leave this question as it stands but if you do post a new question on this, please be sure include the PCA context and then clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your definition of "order statistics" refer to moments in statistics.

The Gaussian distribution is indeed fully specified by the first and second moments, i.e. mean and variance of the distribution.

Other distributions, such as the Laplace distribution for example, are as well characterized by these two first moments.

For the Laplace, the first moment corresponds to both the mean and location parameter $\mu$, while the second moment is $2b^2$ where $b$ is the scale parameter. See the wiki page for more information.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is the current expansion considered as sufficient?